# Pass Keyword in Swift

Tags: swift

I know that the keyword "pass" in Python will allow one to leave a line of code empty where it should have contained an executable statement. Is there a similar keyword in Swift?

I am using a switch statement and Swift requires there to be a default case. The code should reach the default statement most of the time and I want nothing to be done in this case.

Comment: Just comment that line... Why'd u need a keyword??

Comment: it doesn't make any sense to have it for anything language that use braces

Comment: just do `default: break`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can break out of the default case. Swift just wants you to be explicit about that to avoid bugs.

Here's a simple example:

```
enum Food {
    case Banana
    case Apple
    case ChocolateBar
}

func warnIfUnhealthy(food : Food) {
    switch food {
    case .ChocolateBar:
        println("Don't eat it!")

    default:
        break
    }

}

let candy = Food.ChocolateBar

warnIfUnhealthy(candy)
```

Answer (score 7):

The proper way to add a catch-all without an action to a switch statement is to add

```
default: break
```

at the end.